# how can i update json array object value

Tags: postgresql

I have an array object it is not updated object value. 
It always appends a new object in an array.

I have try || operator but it is only working on an object, not array object.
I do the following:

```
UPDATE "chats" SET

                    "groupUserStatus"="groupUserStatus" :: JSONB || '{"1":"viewed"}'

                    WHERE  "chats"."chatType"='groupchat' AND

                    ("chats"."groupUserStatus") :: JSONB @> '{"1":"sent"}' :: JSONB
```

it is updated object successfully but I have update array object.
For Example
Insert Record like this

```
[{"1":"sent"},{"2":"read"}]
```

but how i will get record like this (How update record)

```
[{"1":"viewed"},{"2":"read"}]
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: What is your expected output? `[{"1":"sent", "2":"read"}]`? Or not an array: `{"1":"sent", "2":"read"}`? How does groupUserStatus look like?

Comment: Please provide an example of the original `groupUserStatus` jsonb content and the full expected resulting content (after an update). That will help us much better to provide a solution than to try and describe it. :)

Comment: Insert record like this `[{"1":"sent"},{"2":"read"}]`
out put record (**update record**) like this `[{"1":"viewed"},{"2":"read"}] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jsonb_set`

```
 set groupUserStatus = jsonb_set ( groupUserStatus :: JSONB ,'{0,"1"}', '"viewed"')
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0172e7c0811545c697a7e4a36c962704)

**EDIT** : To get the index dynamically and update, you may have to 
extract the elements of the array and each key value pairs.

```
update t t1 set col = jsonb_set ( t2.col :: JSONB ,
           ('{'||j.idx-1||',"'||e.k||'"}')::text[] , '"viewed"' )
           FROM  t t2 cross join 
   jsonb_array_elements  (t2.col :: JSONB) with ordinality as j(elem,idx)
cross join jsonb_each_text(j.elem) as e(k,v)
where e.v ='sent'
and t1.id = t2.id
```

[**DEMO2**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=11bf5c2176224fe68e01f5b4eb724543)

Comment: How can find index dynamically? @Kaushik

Comment: @GarachAnkur : check edits. Replace the column names accordingly. You would need an key column(a primary key/ unique key of the table) to achieve it, which I have used here as `id`